# Generating own log-file for each test-fragment with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm doing performance-testing and my test consist of several different test fragments. For example one fragment handles logging in, several different fragments which each navigate through different part of the application and so on.

The problem is that I would need log from each different fragment for reporting. Management is interested seeing change over time between the same functionality.

Is JMeter's 'Simple data writer' capable of generating multiple logfiles? or what would be the best way to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: When you say 'fragment', what exactly do you mean? how are you organising the fragments? Different samplers? Different thread groups? You can attach listeners to almost any element type in a JMeter Test Plan.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer after looking at JMeter docs again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm going to try for an answer as there's no response to the comment:

Depending on how you've organised your 'test fragments', you can attach a separate data write to each and use a different filename to record to a different log. For instance, if you had a thread group that simulated one use case and another for another, you'd add a Simple Data Writer to each and use a different filename\path that allows you to know what the resulting logfile does. You can do the same with Samplers and Beanshell scripts.

There's more info in the JMeter docs:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer

Hope this helps, but without more concrete examples, it's difficult to be more specific.

EDIT: I realise now that a test fragment is a specific controller element in JMeter. Just add a Simple Data Writer for each fragment and each one will generate a log file.

Answer (score 0):

One word of warning on the approaches below.

 I got caught out previously having a lot of data writers in a script because Jmeter and its various components all place a small load on your system as the tests are running.

 If you have a lot of Data writers, you could introduce enough additional load to mess up your own results.

 My approach would be to include them whilst building the test scripts and then disable them when actually running the tests.

 You can always selectively re-enable them if you need to, in order to track down errors and problems.